# Browsing/Exploring Android XML in Eclipse

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-layout

Is there any support in Eclipse for tracing XML declarations and assignments for an Android app? For example, I wanted to take a look at the default values for the current theme in my "ToDoListV1" application. The trace looks like this:

```
AppTheme->
AppBaseTheme->
Theme.AppCompat.Light->
Theme.Base.AppCompat.Light->
android:Theme.Holo.Light
```

However, I had to put this together using Search->File, searching for the above strings and figuring out which of the many results were being used. This is really labor intensive (and error prone).

My question is: Is there some kind of XML browser tool/capability/plugin in Eclipse that would allow me to do this (and similar tasks) easily? E.g., by displaying the chain of assignments for a given entity/attribute/item, or at least allow me to select a value in use and jump to its definition.

Here is same trace above, but with the relevant file names.

```
ToDoListV1/AndroidManifest.xml
<application
…
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
…>

TodoListV1/res/values/styles.xml
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
…
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

appcompat_v7/res/values/themes.xml
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Theme.Base.AppCompat.Light">

appcompat_v7/res/values-14/themes_base.xml
<style name="Theme.Base.AppCompat.Light" parent=" android:Theme.Holo.Light ">
```

Thank you for any assistance!

Barry

Comment: Tried `AndroidStudio`? it's more actively supported by Google

Comment: Not yet. Does it provide this capability?